# [Pine code], How can i set Line properties in the style screen?

Tags: pine-script

After the new release of pine v4 i haven't coded any indicator for tradingview, only mt4 indicators. My questions goes to this code, i plotted some lines creating them by the function line.new, after i finished the code i noticed that when i added the indicator to the chart the inputs were ok, but lines had no style properties, only had one button to put it on/off. So my question is simple line properties can be set from style screen or must be defined manually in the code?
Here is an example of the code, when i'm drawing lines.

```
pLevel = (prevHighHTF + prevLowHTF + prevCloseHTF) / 3
r1Level = pLevel * 2 - prevLowHTF
s1Level = pLevel * 2 - prevHighHTF
var line pLine = na
var label pLabel = na
condition1 = pLevel < RANGE1 and pLevel < RANGE2 
condition2 = pLevel > RANGE1 and pLevel > RANGE2 

if pLevel[1] != pLevel and condition1 
line.set_x2(pLine, bar_index)
line.set_extend(pLine, extend.right)
pLine := line.new(bar_index, pLevel, bar_index, pLevel, 
extend=extend.right)
line.set_width(pLine, LineWidth)
line.set_style(pLine, line.style_solid)
line.set_color(pLine, color.green)

if pLevel[1] != pLevel and condition2 
line.set_x2(pLine, bar_index)
line.set_extend(pLine, extend.right)
pLine := line.new(bar_index, pLevel, bar_index, pLevel, 
extend=extend.right)
line.set_color(pLine, color.green)
line.set_width(pLine, LineWidth)
line.set_style(pLine, line.style_solid)

if not na(pLine) and condition1 
line.set_x2(pLine, bar_index)   
line.set_extend(pLine, extend.right)
line.set_color(pLine, color.green)
line.set_width(pLine, LineWidth)
line.set_style(pLine, line.style_solid)

if not na(pLine) and condition2
line.set_x2(pLine, bar_index)   
line.set_extend(pLine, extend.right)
line.set_color(pLine, color.green)
line.set_width(pLine, LineWidth)
line.set_style(pLine, line.style_solid)

keepLastLines = input(700)
lineCount = 0
for i = 1 to maxBarsBack
if not na(pLine[i])
    lineCount := lineCount + 1
    if lineCount > keepLastLines
        line.delete(pLine[i])
```

Hope someone could read this and help me :)

Comment: They must be defined in the script.

Comment: There are other ways to draw the same lines? like plot function?

Comment: Yes, sure. While `plot()` provides more visual controls, it is not as flexible when you need to position lines at a given place retroactively, and it plots bar by bar, whereas with `line.new()` you can plot a complete line from any bar.

`plot()` has an offset parameter allowing you to plot in the past, but it must be constant throughout the script's execution, so not ideal for all situations. Your choice of a line-plotting function will vary depending on what your needs are.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Well, still got another question, for you, i got the code of pivot points from the public library of tradingview website (https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Drawings.html?highlight=pivot#pivot-points-standard), is the same code for the built in pivot point indicator? as the pivot point provided by tradingview platform has options in the style window, like color, width and other stuff, but this can't be done with the code shown in the public library... i don't understand that, do u have any idea?

Comment: Hi, The built-in version is not written in Pine and uses features not available in Pine.

Comment: Ohhhh snap, well i'm still looking for optional solutions... the number of drawings with the line.new() function can be limited to a certain amount? if its possible how can be done?

Comment: See http://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-keep-only-the-last-x-labels-or-lines

Comment: I edited the question with the full code, but still don't know why do i have to use a bigger number than lines shown in the chart, seems that every single line plotted it's made of 100 lines each.

Comment: Still there LucF ???

Comment: Well, I answered your original question and provided additional info on 2 follow-up questions in further comments. SO isn't on-going support. If you have an additional unrelated question involving code that's not working, then you should post compilable and properly formatted code in a new question, along with a chart explaining what your problem is.